# websocket backend deploy using cloud run

Tags: linux, docker, go, google-cloud-platform

So i have a linux executable of a game and an html file that acts as an interface for the executable.The linux executable is a backend of some basic games it ensures that players in a game can play efficiently and according to the rule.
this is working perfectly while im testing using the docker but getting errors when after deployment on google cloud.

I dockerized and tested it locally ,it worked perfectly.Here are the logs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yua4S.png)

But when im testing it after deployment on google cloud,it works well in the start ,but then i get a warning and the i dont get logs afterwards.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdkuw.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.